# Error trying to post JSON data to Android Device

Tags: java, android, json, google-cloud-messaging

I've followed the tutorial [here](http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/) in an attempt to send data to an android device. I've whittled my Java class down to this:

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        try {                   
            String apiKey = "api key generated in Google Developer Console...";
            String deviceId = "Device Id generated, retrieved directly from logcat, as per tutorial...";
            Content content = new Content();

            content.addRegId(deviceId);
            content.createData("Title", "Notification Message");
            URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + apiKey);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            mapper.writeValue(wr, content);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(responseCode == 200 ? responseCode + ". This is the response we want..." : responseCode + ". This is not the response we want...");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            System.out.println(response.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and this is my Content class:

```
public class Content implements Serializable{

    private List<String> registration_ids;
    private Map<String,String> data;

    public void addRegId(String regId) {
        if(registration_ids == null)
            registration_ids = new LinkedList<String>();
        registration_ids.add(regId);        
    }

    public void createData(String title, String message) {
        if (data == null) 
            data = new HashMap<String,String>();

        data.put("title", title);
        data.put("message",  message);
    }

}
```

I'm getting a 400 response code

`java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`

I'm sure I'm missing something small, but I can't see where it is.

Comment: Response code 400 means you have a bad request

Comment: you maybe try to use Volley Framework with GSON, is more simple to handle network operation. Some example: https://github.com/balduzzi85/android_volley_examples

Comment: @AntonioBalduzzi thanks, I have been looking at using Volley. I did want to get this simple example working before moving on to something else though

Comment: One question, why to you have  `public static void main( String[] args )`  in an Android app?

Comment: @DanielNugent this is just a Java application which should be sending a message to a specific android device.

Comment: Please double check your content object. I dont think it is successfully transformed into a JSON object. Also, please follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vd8bIkE29U4) step by step, I followed and succeed implement `GCM`

Comment: Thanks @bjiang. I had looked at that video, which is almost identical to the [original link](http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/) that I'd posted in my question. Completed the tutorial again this evening and it worked fine. Comparing code now to determine where my error was.

Comment: Yeah, but it works:)

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I had a similar one and solved by using `writeBytes(String)` instead of `writeChars(String)` or other methods to output my JSON.

Comment: @Piovezan Yeah, solved it by following the tutorial on YouTube mentioned in @bjiang's comment above rather than the tutorial I had originally listed. Just had to change one line: Instead of `mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);` I changed that to `mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);`